# Spresenseでmp3が再生されない

Tags: spresense, mp3

Spresenseでmp3プレイヤーを作っています
Sprenseには書き込みが可能ですか、いざ曲を流してみると
短い曲の場合は流れず、長い場合は
流れません。
Spresense自体ではどのぐらいの長さまで流せますか❓
また、その上限を変えることは可能ですか
曲は約一時間です
又、sdカードの容量はあり、圧縮状態も他のmp3 と同じです

Comment: 本文の書き方だと「短い曲」と「長い曲」のどちらも「流れない(再生されない)」になっていますが、書き間違えでしょうか？ / 再生するために行った手順やコードなどがあればそれらも質問文に含めてもらったほうがアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Comment: この辺が参考になるかも。[Spresenseでハイレゾ音楽プレーヤーをつくってみよう！](https://deviceplus.jp/hobby/spresense-02/), [SPRESENSEでMP3オーディオを再生してみた！](https://makers-with-myson.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2018-11-28), [SONY SPRESENSEでハイレゾを再生する](http://jamnopapa.blogspot.com/2018/09/sony-spresense.html), [ハイレゾの再生](https://www.denshi.club/cookbook/arduino/spresense/spresensel-7-hairezonosaisei.html), [音楽再生](http://spresense.livedoor.blog/archives/10972275.html)